# How to Parse a JSON Object In Android

Tags: android, json

I am having some problems pulling values from a JSON object. Here is my code

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("results");
    test = json2.getString("name");     
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`test` is declared as a `String`. When the code runs it is showing `null`. If I hover over `json2` in debug mode I can see all the values and names within the object.

I also tried

```
test = json2.length();
```

This returned `test = 0`. Even when I hover over the `json2` object I can read the values within the object.

Here is an example of a JSON string I will use.

```
{
    "caller":"getPoiById",
    "results":
    {
        "indexForPhone":0,
        "indexForEmail":"NULL",
        "indexForHomePage":"NULL",
        "indexForComment":"NULL",
        "phone":"05137-930 68",
        "cleanPhone":"0513793068",
        "internetAccess":"2",
        "overnightStay":"2",
        "wasteDisposal":"2",
        "toilet":"2",
        "electricity":"2",
        "cran":"2",
        "slipway":"2",
        "camping":"2",
        "freshWater":"2",
        "fieldNamesWithValue":["phone"],
        "fieldNameTranslations": ["Telefon"],
        "id":"1470",
        "name":"Marina Rasche Werft GmbH & Co. KG",
        "latitude":"52.3956107286487",
        "longitude":"9.56583023071289"
    }
}
```

Comment: JSON string example you provided works for me at least. Are you facing problems with that string too?

Comment: can you show the whole code for this?or atleast help me with my problem with jsonobject

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the end I solved it by using `JSONObject.get` rather than `JSONObject.getString` and then cast `test` to a `String`.

```
private void saveData(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject json= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
        JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("results");
        test = (String) json2.get("name");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem and solved it by following your approach. Did you look for/manage to find an explanation why this works but getJSONObject doesn't ?

Comment: because your json is an object and not an array so you use Jsonobject

Answer (score 14):

In your JSON format, it do not have starting JSON object

Like :

```
{
    "info" :       <!-- this is starting JSON object -->
        {
        "caller":"getPoiById",
        "results":
        {
            "indexForPhone":0,
            "indexForEmail":"NULL",
            .
            .
         }
    }
}
```

Above Json starts with `info` as JSON object. So while executing :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);    // create JSON obj from string
JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("info");    // this will return correct
```

Now, we can access `result` field :

```
JSONObject jsonResult = json2.getJSONObject("results");
test = json2.getString("name"); // returns "Marina Rasche Werft GmbH & Co. KG"
```

I think this was missing and so the problem was solved while we use `JSONTokener` like answer of yours.

Your answer is very fine. Just i think i add this information so i answered

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

This might fix your issue.

Comment: I posted the updated code above, but I still have the same problem @Dave G

Answer (score 6):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject obj1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONArray results = patient.getJSONArray("results");
     String indexForPhone =  patientProfile.getJSONObject(0).getString("indexForPhone"));
}
```

Change to JSONArray, then convert to JSONObject.