# How to parse the below JSON to retrieve data from web service in Android

Tags: android, json

Hello I have the `JSON` given below, how i can retrieve data by passing parameters into method given in (for android) :

JSON:

```
{
  "transport": "POST",
  "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
  "contentType": "application\/json",
  "SMDVersion": "2.0",
  "target": "\/index.php",
  "services": {
    "search": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "name": "criterias",
          "optional": false
        }
      ],
      "returns": "array"
    },
    "getDayConferences": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "integer",
          "name": "nb_day",
          "optional": false
        }
      ],
      "returns": "array"
    },
    "getParticipants": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [

      ],
      "returns": "array"
    },
    "getAllForLocation": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "float",
          "name": "latitude",
          "optional": false
        },
        {
          "type": "float",
          "name": "longitude",
          "optional": false
        }
      ],
      "returns": "array"
    }
  },
  "methods": {
    "search": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "name": "criterias",
          "optional": false
        }
      ],
      "returns": "array"
    },
    "getDayConferences": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "integer",
          "name": "nb_day",
          "optional": false
        }
      ],
      "returns": "array"
    },
    "getParticipants": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [

      ],
      "returns": "array"
    },
    "getAllForLocation": {
      "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
      "transport": "POST",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "float",
          "name": "latitude",
          "optional": false
        },
        {
          "type": "float",
          "name": "longitude",
          "optional": false
        }
      ],
      "returns": "array"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for help..

Comment: try to use GSON library or refer this to parse response yourself- see here=> http://stackoverflow.com/a/5581922/1225413

Comment: I have seen some examples but the problem is in that data from json is straight forward. In the JSON data posted by me i have functions like searc, getDayConference etc whihc i need to call to get data. I am confussed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most straightforward solution is to use [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) if you dont mind writting a lot of code.

However, you can try to look for some utils that provide mapping Json data to the POJO.

**P.S. Please try to make some research before posting the question to StackOverflow.**

Comment: I have done some search but couldn't find any source or example which shows how to get data from this type of JSON. thnks for for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get data from network first, I suggest to use Volley network library for that.
   https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138
2. You can use GSON library to parse json data to object.
   http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

That's all