# How to get json object in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i want to fetch some data which is in json format but i don't know how to fetch. Please guide me.

Json data:-

```
{
    "title":"title",
        "description":"description",
        "icon":{
    "url":"<image-url>",
            "aspectRatio":1,
            "height":75,
            "width":75
},
    "screenshots":{
    "url":"<image-url>",
            "aspectRatio":1.91,
            "height":627,
            "width":1200
},
    "landingURL":"LandingUrl",
        "cta":"cta",
        "rating":"rating"
}
```

Comment: Till now what you have tried??

Comment: Possible duplicae of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566669/how-to-parse-a-json-object-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Put your response in Jsonobject.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

and parse your json.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
String description = jsonObject.getString("description");
JSONObject iconObject = jsonObject.JSONObject("icon");
```

This is how you can parse your json data. but it is even better to use [Gson](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following code:

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
     String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
     String description = jsonObject.getString("description");
     JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("icon");
         if(jObj.has("url")) {
            String url = jObj.getString("url");
            int aspectRatio = jObj.getInt("aspectRatio");
            int height = jObj.getInt("height");
            int width = jObj.getInt("width");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```