# How to access java.lang.Object json value in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, json

I have this code and `System.out.println(tempObj);` print this json(`I/System.out: {id=830, dish_id=789, dish_size=Small, price=21, weight=350, promo_price=, dishes_num_for_promo=0}`), can you please help me how to access these json value in JAVA Android

```
for(int i=0; i<disSizes.length; i++ ){
        Object tempObj =  disSizes[i];

        System.out.println(disSizes);
        System.out.println(tempObj);

    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566669/how-to-parse-a-json-object-in-android

Comment: Directly Print the JSON obj in logcat Log.e(TAG,obj.toString) and see the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to parse the JSONObject:

```
private void parseDishData(JSONObject jsonObj){
    try{
        int dishId = jsonObj.optInt("dish_id", -1);
        String disSizes = jsonObj.optString("dish_size", "NA");
        String price = jsonObj.optString("price", "NA");
        Log.e("MyDishData", "dishId = " + dishId + " disSizes = " +  disSizes)
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Or if you have a `String` you can use this code to parse the JSON String:

```
private void parseDishData(String json){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        int dishId = jsonObj.optInt("dish_id", -1);
        String disSizes = jsonObj.optString("dish_size", "NA");
        String price = jsonObj.optString("price", "false");
        Log.e("MyDishData", "dishId = " + dishId + " disSizes = " +  disSizes)
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Just pass the `parseDishData` method the JSON string.

---

**EDIT:**

Your error:

> E/ERROR: Expected literal value at character 73 of {id=830,
>   dish_id=789, dish_size=Small, price=21, weight=350, promo_price=,
>   dishes_num_for_promo=0

You are getting the above error because there appears to be a problem with the JSON string. The key " promo_price" has no value! "promo_price=,". There should be a value for example: "promo_price=10,".

Comment: Getting this error E/ERROR: Expected literal value at character 73 of {id=830, dish_id=789, dish_size=Small, price=21, weight=350, promo_price=, dishes_num_for_promo=0}

Comment: tempObj varibale is java.lang.Object

Comment: @UmashankarSaw :: There appears to be an issue with the JSON string. The key " promo_price" has no value! "promo_price=,"

Comment: @UmashankarSaw :: Have you had a chance to look at the explanation of why you are getting the error. If you need any help with that, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `JSONObject` by casting the object:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) tempObj;
```

Now you can access the properties by using the appropriate getters from the `JSONObject` class according to the type of data you want to get out of it.

For instance you do:

```
int id = json.getInt("id");
```

to obtain the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You will cast `Object` to `JSONObject` to extract values from this Json.

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) tempObj;
```

Then you can parse Json by simple methods like

```
String promo_price = json.getString("promo_price");
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer provided by @NiVeR ?